# DisplayActionSheet in .Net MAUI only working intermittently in Windows

Tags: maui

I have a cross-platform mobile application which I currently develop and debug in 'Windows Machine' then release and test further in Android.  It's using .Net 7.0 running on Windows 10.

I ran into a problem when trying to use DisplayActionSheet.  It would not appear on the first attempt but execution would continue on the next statement.  Then, I noticed that if I set the next execution line back to the call to DisplayActionSheet it would eventually display. So I set up this loop in 'MainPage.xaml.cs' behind a button to test the theory:

```
int intTryLoopCntr = 0;
while (intTryLoopCntr < 100)
{
    intTryLoopCntr++;
    var action = "";
    int intTryCntr = 0;
    while (!((action != null) && ((action != ""))) && (intTryCntr < 10))
    {
        intTryCntr++;
        action = await DisplayActionSheet("Share message by...(" + intTryCntr + ")", "Cancel", "Delete", "SMS", "Email", "WhatsApp");
        if (action == "Cancel")
                intTryLoopCntr = 99999; // Exit test loop by clicking 'Cancel'
    }
}
```

As it ran I noticed that the failure was only on the first or second attempt.  After that it executed properly every time.

Searching for a solution I only found this on a bug report ([DisplayActionSheet not opening the action dialog on Windows #3726](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/3726)) that was supposedly fixed a year ago.  Am I incorrect in assuming they would fix the bug in .Net 7.0?

Does anyone know why this is happening and whether there is something I can do to fix it without waiting for a bug fix?
[Edited to include more detail]

Comment: 1. Please add to question the link to that bug report. 2. v6 or v7 of what? 3. Is that code running on MainThread? It needs to.

Comment: Sorry,  ToolmakerSteve.  See edits.

Comment: Yes, it should be fixed in current version of .Net 7.0. See (3.) in my first comment. Details at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/main-thread. Because you need `await`, add `async` to code snippet: `MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread( async () => { ... await DisplayActionSheet ... });` UNLESS you have multiple windows, in which case you'll need Dispatcher from window that is displaying the DisplayActionSheet.

Comment: Thank you, ToolmakerSteve.  I've upgraded to VS 17.6.2 and it appears to be fixed.  The coded posted above is indicating that it works the first time, as it should.  I'll put it through some further scrutiny and indicate here whether the issue is resolved so this post can be closed.  Also, I didn't include the async/await in the snippet because I was focused on solving the immediate issue.  The first testing attempt included async/await but I eliminated it to get a bare bones test.

Comment: Follow up: bug still exists.  At your suggestion I'll try the async/await again, but I recall the results clearly and it had no effect.  This code is called from the MainPage (startup ContentPage).

Comment: @jbecker Consider it's a potential issue if it's still not working after upgrading to `.Net 7.0`. And there's an existing one:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/14829 on Github, you can follow up there.

Comment: bug still exists